# Showing that the Klein 4-group $V_4$ and the cyclic group $Z_4$ are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

How do you show that the Klein $4$-group $V_4$ and $Z_4$ are not isomorphic? I want to use the following fact:

> If $f\colon G \to H$ is an isomorphism, then $|f(x)| = |x|$ for all $x \in G.$

Comment: All non-identity elements of $K_4$ have order $2$.  Can you find an element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that has order greater than $2$?

Comment: Show some work. There are just 3 elements other than identity. You can find the orders of all 3 elements in both the groups and compare.

Comment: What is your definition of the klein group? are you using a Cayley table?

Answer (score 2):

The group $Z_4$ is cyclic and it's generator has order four. If you did have an isomorphism $f\colon Z_4 \to V_4$, is there an element of order four in $V_4$ for that generator to map to?